# How to make a SQL query partial match with substrings not in the beginning

Tags: sql, mariadb

Let's say there is a column called: `m_report_notation`

Said column, has values such as: `NM_004004.5:c.235del (p.L79Cfs*3)`

And I would like that, if the value of `v` is, for example: `235del`, then get `NM_004004.5:c.235del (p.L79Cfs*3)` as a result.

This is my current query and what I've tried so far (using MariaDB connector for Django):

```
    sql="SELECT a.*, COALESCE( NULLIF(a.c_ref_gene, '.'), NULLIF(a.gd_ref_gene, '.') ) AS variant, b.*, c.* FROM `db-dummy`.s_g_data c JOIN `db-dummy`.g_info a ON a.record_id = c.g_id JOIN `db-dummy`.s_data b ON b.record_id = c.s_id WHERE a.gene_name LIKE concat(?, '%') AND a.m_report_notation LIKE concat(?, '%') AND b.s_id LIKE concat(?, '%') ORDER BY a.gene_name LIMIT 30;"
    data = (g, v, s)
    cursor.execute(sql, data)
```

If for example, `v = NM_00` I will get a list of results starting with `NM_00`, but what if the substring that I'm introducing it's not in the beginning? What if is something like `“235del”`?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I did, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for `like`?

```
where m_report_notation like concat('%', ?, '%')
```